# Play audio file in Cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, blender, 3dsmax, cocos3d

I'm using **Blender** tool to create models,I have included the animations and audio in the model and exported in POD format. Now when I run the POD file in iOS app using Cocos3d, the animation runs fine but not the audio which I have included.

So my question is "Can we include audio in the POD files?"

If **YES** "Why isn't it playing?"

If **NO** "How can I play it using Cocos3d?And I have to start playing the audio at a particular frame."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POD` files are strictly binary 3D model files. There is no audio track available within a `POD` file.

**Cocos3D** audio support is provided by the *Cocos2D* framework.

In **Cocos3D**, animation is run by the `CC3ActionAnimate` action. As far as synchronizing audio with animation timeframes, you might try creating a `CCActionSequence` containing the following actions in sequence:

1. `CC3ActionAnimate` to animate the node up to the point where you want to play your sound effect.
2. `CCActionCallBlock` to start the audio effect playing
3. `CC3ActionAnimate` to animate the remaining content of the node animation.

Or you could just run a single `CC3ActionAnimate` for the entire animation, and, at the same time, run a separate `CCActionSequence` containing a `CCActionDelay` and `CCActionCallBlock` to start the audio after a certain delay.

...Bill